# When and Where to use Kubernetes Pod Affinity Rules

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I'm trying to understand if it is good practice to use a `podAntiAffinity` rule to prefer that `Pod`'s in my `Deployment` avoid being scheduled on the same node. Thus spreading the `Pod`'s out on my Kubernetes cluster.

```
affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 100
      podAffinityTerm:
        labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: "app.kubernetes.io/name"
            operator: In
            values:
            - "foo"
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) suggests avoiding the use of `podAntiAffinity` for clusters with hundreds of nodes which suggests that there is a performance impact to using them.

Also, if I don't use them, isn't the default scheduler behaviour to space out `Pod`'s anyway?

I suppose it also matters what the `Deployment` is for. It makes sense to use a `podAntiAffinity` for a Redis cache for example but wouldn't it make even more sense to use a `DaemonSet` for that case? Also, what is the recommendation for a web server `Pod`?

Answer (score 0):

You use Pod/Node Affinity rules if you want to schedule pods on some nodes by matching specified condition in more expressive methods. I am not sure if you can use it to avoid being scheduled on same node. 
If you don't use affinity rule, then kube-scheduler will look for feasible node to schedule pod on it and this is generally is not the same node.

You make kube-scheduler "to think" more by defining affinity rules and this is normal that in big clusters it can affect to performance.

Also to understand how the kube-scheduler iterates over Nodes by default, you can check [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/scheduler-perf-tuning/#how-the-scheduler-iterates-over-nodes).